# Need help in booting to windows

Tags: debian, windows, dual-boot

Previously, I had dual booted debian with win 10 in a HDD. Recently, I removed my debian in HDD and installed debian in a new SSD. During the process, I have deleted the efi partition in the HDD. Now, in new SSD, I have a efi partition which opens debian. I need help to boot into windows os, although I can access the files in the debian as a mount partition. File structure is as follows
/dev/sda1 is root
/dev/sda3 is /boot/efi

/dev/sdb2 is windows partition.

I tried os-prober. No use anyway. Suggestions to correct this please.

Comment: If you deleted the efi partition you likely removed the Windows boot sector. You need to use a Windows recovery disk to fix this.

Comment: Try Windows "bootrec" utility, that will probably "hide" Debian instead. If that's the case then boot from a Debian Live and do an "update-grub".